# Determine if $U$ is a subspace of $P_3\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U=\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d|a+d=b,\text{ },a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\}$

This is what my solution says, and I have a few questions about it:

[image]

I understand how they rewrote the polynomial, and how it can be expressed as a span of $3$ vectors, but how does this **prove its a subspace**?

The solution I am used to is prove $U$ non empty, that if $U_1,U_2\in U\to U_1+U_2\in U$, and $U_1\in U\to rU_1\in U, r\in\mathbb{R}$

Is the solution given here incorrect?

Comment: That's because the standard condition is obviously fulfilled by polynomials which can be written as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U$ is spanned *freely* by three vectors, namely $x^3+x^2,x$ and $x^2+1$. This is because the scalars which are their coefficients are free to vary among the real numbers. This property is enough to make $U$ into a subspace.

The presentation of $U$ should make it clear enough why the definitions hold:

$$
(a(x^3+x^2) + cx + d(x^2+1)) + (a'(x^3+x^2) + c'x + d'(x^2+1)) \\= (a+a')(x^3+x^2) + (c+c')x + (d+d')(x^2+1) \in U
$$
showing that $U$ is closed under addition.
$$
C(a(x^3+x^2) + cx + d(x^2+1)) = (Ca)(x^3+x^2) + (Cc)x + (Cd)(x^2+1) \in U
$$
showing that $U$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

It is clear that $0 \in U$, so $U$ is non-empty, and a subspace by the above conditions.

> More generally, the span of a non-empty subset of vectors is a subspace of the space the vectors are taken from. You can use reasoning similar to that shown above to conclude this.

The reason why your text did not want to go through this step, is probably because it expected you to see it yourself.